# How to run program installed with pip3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Stupid question, but I cannot google the answer :/.

I used pip3 to to install mps-youtube

```
pip3 install mps-youtube youtube-dl
```

How to run it now?

I tried to do that with environment activated and disactivated. pip3 show tells me that file is in: .local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

typing mps-youtube, python mps-youtube, python3 mps-youtube gives file not exists.

When I get to .local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mps-youtube there is no any file looking like a file which I can run or copy to /usr/bin...

Thx.

K.

Answer (score 1):

In most Linux systems, programs installed with Pip are un `~/.local/bin` folder. If it is the case, you could simply add the folder to the PATH:

```sh
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

(I know the question is three years old, I stumbled on this problem today and I see this unanswered question. So as I found the answer I thought it was a good idea to post it here)